# What is the benefit of using non-blocking sockets with the "select" function?

Tags: sockets, unix, network-programming

I'm writing a server in Linux that will have to support simultaneous read/write operations from multiple clients.  I want to use the *select* function to manage read/write availability.

What I don't understand is this: Suppose I want to wait until a socket has data available to be read.  The documentation for *select* states that it blocks until there is data available to read, and that the read function will not block.

So if I'm using select and I know that the read function will not block, why would I need to set my sockets to non-blocking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There might be cases when a socket is reported as ready but by the time you get to check it, it changes its state.

One of the good examples is accepting connections. When a new connection arrives, a listening socket is reported as ready for read. By the time you get to call accept, the connection might be closed by the other side before ever sending anything and before we called `accept`. Of course, the handling of this case is OS-dependent, but it's possible that `accept` will simply block until a new connection is established, which will cause our application to wait for indefinite amount of time preventing processing of other sockets. If your listening socket is in a non-blocking mode, this won't happen and you'll get `EWOULDBLOCK` or some other error, but `accept` will not block anyway.

Some kernels used to have (I hope it's fixed now) an interesting bug with UDP and `select`. When a datagram arrives `select` wakes up with the socket with datagram being marked as ready for read. The datagram checksum validation is postponed until a user code calls `recvfrom` (or some other API capable of receiving UDP datagrams). When the code calls `recvfrom` and the validating code detects a checksum mismatch, a datagram is simply dropped and `recvfrom` ends up being blocked until a next datagram arrives. One of the patches fixing this problem (along with the problem description) can be found [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.commits.head/44781).

Answer (score 4):

Other than the kernel bugs mentioned by others, a different reason for choosing non-blocking sockets, even with a polling loop, is that it allows for greater performance with fast-arriving data. Think what happens when a blocking socket is marked as "readable". You have no idea how much data has arrived, so you can safely read it only once. Then you have to get back to the event loop to have your poller check whether the socket is still readable. This means that for every single read from or write to the socket you have to do at least two system calls: the `select` to tell you it's safe to read, and the reading/writing call itself.

With non-blocking sockets you can skip the unnecessary calls to `select` after the first one. When a socket is flagged as readable by `select`, you have the option of reading from it as long as it returns data, which allows faster processing of quick bursts of data.

Comment: Thanks, very good point, I didn't know that trying to read would be faster than another select.

Answer (score 3):

This going to sound snarky but it isn't.  The best reason to make them non-blocking is so you don't block.

Think about it.  `select()` tells you there is something to read but you don't know how much.  Could be 2 bytes, could be 2,000.  In most cases it more efficient to drain whatever data is there before going back to `select`.  So you enter a while loop to read

```
while (1)
{
    n = read(sock, buffer, 200);
    //check return code, etc
}
```

What happens on the last read when there is nothing left to read?  If the socket isn't non-blocking you will block, thereby defeating (at least partially) the point of the `select()`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the benefits, is that it will catch any programming errors you make, because if you try to read a socket that would normally block you, you'll get EWOULDBLOCK instead. For objects other than sockets, the exact api behaviour may change, see http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/nonblocking.html.